# Node_JS with Ionic isn't installing packages correctly

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

When I try to create a new Ionic project then it will install files in the main project folder. I'm using Windows 10, with the latest version of Ionic and Node_JS.

It looks like this:
[image: It looks like this:]

[image: image 2]

It should be something like this, when creating a new project:
[image: It should be something like this, when creating a new project:]

If someone who experienced similar problems could help me then it would be greatly appreciated.

Ionic info gives me this:

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.0.0
    Ionic CLI        : 3.0.0

System:

    Node       : v6.10.3
    OS         : Windows 10
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
```

Comment: you want to install ionic v1 or v3? and what does `ionic info` give?

Comment: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44000124/edit) your question and add there..